# How to connect SharePoint 2016 to new Active Directory server

Tags: active-directory, dns, server

Our Active Directory server has problems. So, we decide to create a new Active Directory server and restore backup to new Active Directory server.

When DNS SharePoint servers and Database server change to

Preferred DNS server=  new active directory server ip

and

Alternative DNS server= old active directory server ip

Then resart servers. the SharePoint site and Central admin cannot open
I'm getting the following error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

The error   in Front-end Server Log :

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at...

Is there anything in SharePoint that need to be configure?
How can I  connect new Active directory server to SharePoint?
Any suggestions/comments?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a new SharePoint farm and restore content database/services app databases (but not Config or Admin) to it.

Moving Active Directory domains, which is what you're effectively doing, is not supported by SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks.the problem is the domain name will stay the same, but the ip address will change.
How about
Central admin, user profile, synchronization, configure synchronization connection 
can sync domain name with new Active Directory?

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109206/will-sharepoint-be-upset-if-we-move-the-domain-controller-and-dns-server

Thanks

Comment: Did you build a new Active Directory domain or perform an authoritative restore? If it is new, even if it is the same name, the domain will have a new RID/SID and is not the same Active Directory domain.

Comment: Thanks.I apologize for asking many questions. it is new a Active Directory, if we restore backup (old active directory ) to new Active Directory. Is SID as the same as previous SID? i access both active directories.how to check and compare SID old an new one. What would you do if you were me? please help.

Comment: Also Is it possible to create account in new Active Directory and Sharepoint central open with that. and then I sync sharepoint with new Active Directory?

Comment: Follow this guide - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/ad-forest-recovery-guide. Again, you cannot simply join the SharePoint servers to a new domain, it isn't just about service accounts no matter how you attempt to slice it.